# grunt phonegap-build issue

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, phonegap-build

i have used grunt phonegap-build . i am following this [grunt phonegap-build](https://github.com/centralway/grunt-PhoneGap-build)

gruntjs file:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
    "phonegap-build": {
          debug: {
                    options: {
                            archive: "nan14.zip",
                            "appId": "565756",
                             "user": {
                                    "email": "angappandsgdfk@yahoo.in",
                                    "password": "******"
                                  },
                            "timeout":700000
                     }
         },
         download: {
                    ios: 'dist/ios.ipa',
                    android: 'dist/android.apk'
                    //blackberry: 'dist/blackberry.ota',
                   // winphone: 'dist/winphone.xap'
                }

    }

  });
```

Error:

```
 Running "phonegap-build:debug" (phonegap-build) task
>> Starting upload
>> Upload successful (HTTP 200)

Running "phonegap-build:download" (phonegap-build) task
Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.
```

can you help me? how to download the apk? File uploaded successfuly. i did check my adobe account but not get apk download issue. how to solve this? Help me

Comment: can you share application's main file?

Comment: sorry , which file you want? i didn't understand , ionic config.xml file or?

Comment: Check that you have `dist` directory in your current location. This can cause such kind of errors.

Comment: ya i have created the dist directory

Comment: Thanks all .. I got it